# Can third-order phase transitions be understood from a symmetry-breaking viewpoint?

Tags: symmetry, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, mean-field-theory

First-order phase transitions like solid-fluid can be understood as breaking of translational symmetry into lattice symmetry (also rotations into discrete rotations). The characteristic of these transitions are latent heat. In general the first derivative of the free energy diverges.

Second-order phase transitions can be phenomenologically modeled using Landau-Ginzburg formalism. Here spontaneous breaking of symmetry gives rise to different phases of matter. Spontaneous symmetry breaking predicts the values of the critical constants to a good approximation.

We also know a few examples of third-order phase transitions. To list a couple, we have the Gross–Witten–Wadia and Douglas–Kazakov large-N phase transitions. I was trying to understand if this phase transition can also be explained in terms of symmetry breaking. Are there known arguments in literature which explain third order phase transition from this viewpoint?

EDIT: I found my answer [here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59499/268230)